# getting current url from default android browser on any event action

Tags: android, browser, overriding, bookmarks, homescreen

Im trying to create an application. I have launched the default android browser from the main activity using intent as

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

After launching the browser, I need to customise the browser functionality such that when a user long press or tap the browser window, the current url should be saved as a shortcut in the homescreen. How can I implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can not monitor browser action like long press or tap the browser window.
But you can do other way, like implementing "Share action".
When user want to create short cut, just tell them to do "Share action".
[Adding an Easy Share Action](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

Comment: will the share action work for the default android browser? Since my requirement is to create the shortcut dynamically while the user is still browsing and without the browser exit.